# Bootstrap dropdown button disappears after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

The button which should unhide the dropdown menu actually hides the dropdown button instead. Also, I have one more dropdown menu in this navigation and it works perfectly fine.

```
<div class="side-nav pull-right">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id = "dropdownMenuButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bonjour Arthur K. <img src = "images/triangle.png" alt =""/> </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">    
      <a href="#" title="Utilisateurs">Utilisateurs</a>
      <a href="#" title="Snippets">Snippets</a>
      <a href="#" title="Traductions">Traductions</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="profile">Mon compete</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

check this working example.. for more read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#examples)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```